# I Edited Someone's Question Yesterday; Can I Find That Edit On My Network Activitiy Profile?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I don't recall the details.

The question was at either ELL or ELU, and it included an example which was (I thought) incoherent. I made some little rearrangement of the words. I think the example compared Beowulf and his big battle with some other change that will not be a big battle.

Anyhow, I made the edit and I received that notice that my edit would be reviewed.

None of that shows up in my network profile under "all activity"?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It would appear in your network profile (under Revisions) if the suggested edit could have been approved.

In fact it does appear in your ELU profile under "All actions → suggestions", but the author also edited the post while your suggestion was pending, so your suggestion was automatically rejected, and didn't become a revision. It's not clear whether he based his edit on your suggestion.

> [image: Profile page]

https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/260158

Carry on to 2000 rep and you won't need your edits to be reviewed: they will be implemented immediately.

Comment: I feel dense, but I still cannot find that. I go to EL&U, and click the red square icon near the top of the screen that represents me. My profile comes up. But I cannot find the word "suggestions", and the browser's search function doesn't find it either.

Comment: One bad thing about moderator tools is that we can't tell if they're mod-only or available to everyone. This may be mod-only. However, the analysis is correct: you didn't create a revision, I'm afraid.

Comment: So it turns out that generally, if I'm not a moderator, I propose an edit and that's the end of it; I see no sign of that proposal anywhere in my profile. But if the edit is approved and takes effect, I will simply see the edited question or answer, just like everyone else will, still with no sign of my hand.

Comment: No: if the edit is approved, you will create that revision, which will be shown in your profile, and your name and avatar will be shown against it. Hardly "no sign". I'm on my phone at the moment and can't easily check non-mod functionality.

Comment: @Chaim Added an image from a site I'm not a moderator on. Suggested edits go under "suggestions" and I'd expect your rejected edit to be shown for you.

Comment: I just added an image to my post that seems to correspond to your image. It's from my EL&U profile, and does not include the word "suggestions."

Comment: Click "All actions" to get the submenu which includes "Suggestions".

Comment: Yeah, you were right. The word Suggestions does in fact appear when I click All Actions. Then, if I click Suggestions, I get the statement (now edited into my question): You have no suggestions.

Comment: If they are applied, edits to other people's posts can also be found under revisions (alongside your own edits to your own posts). The additional clutter might make it harder to find them there, if you edit your posts often, but I think it is still important for people who reach the 2000 rep. threshold, since, at least to the best of my understanding, once you reach that point, you can no longer suggest edits because as already mentioned, they are automatically applied.