# Is this a valid question under computer tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is this a valid question under computer tag?

[Is there a word for each component of a Time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461170/is-there-a-word-for-each-component-of-a-time). There is no description or guidelines for  computer tag.

So, how to use this tag, if there is no guidelines available?

**Updated** : My suggestion for the `computer` tag is accepted.

Comment: I don't understand why you would tag any question about English with "computer". The [help] says [A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) - I don't see how "computer" is the topic of this question. Why wouldn't you choose "time" instead? Or maybe use "computing" which has a description?

Comment: @ColleenV because it was closed with this [argument](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461170/is-there-a-word-for-each-component-of-a-time#comment1111907_461170). I am new and I am still learning new things about SE ELU.

Comment: @ColleenV secondly, I forgot to mention that "computer" tag is available on SE ELU.

Comment: People can create tags just be typing them once they have enough reputation - you should prefer tags that have a description. But tagging a question differently doesn't make it on-topic - you need to edit it to make it clear that the question isn't about naming something.

Comment: @ColleenV Oh! I see. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a **HOT META POST**. Congratulations on making the Big Time.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of a tag as a way to steer your question to a particular group of experts. Experts have the ability to filter questions by tag and see just the questions they will be good at answering.

The "computer" tag has no description, and there are only 41 questions across the site with that tag. So it's a good bet that it's not going to help you get an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I wrongly suggested `computer` tag to OP. Later, I got to know that here is  `time` tag.

Comment: @ubihatt Yes -- and the good news for you is that the "time" tag has 439 questions and 2 watchers (experts subscribing to it). You can look up statistics on a tag by going to the "tags" section of the site.

Comment: @ubihatt Or, I should say, the good news for the asker.

Comment: Yeah! I suppose. OP accepted both of my suggestions in the course of 1 hour. So, I guess OP is actively looking for replies.

Comment: @ubihatt The OP probably didn't see the suggestions, much less approve them. The first edit was approved by tchrist (who as a mod can approve edits on his own) and the other was approved by me and another regular user. You can see links to your suggested edits in [your profile](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10918/191178) (and in the edit history of the question, if the edit was approved). For example, the details of the one suggested edit can be seen [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/302816).

Answer (score 3):

### It looks OK to me.

I can't see anything wrong with the question.  The scope is a little narrow, but it could potentially be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Totally agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the question (as of Revision 2) isn't about computers specifically, so I wouldn't have added that tag.

The [computer] tag, I think, should be used for (English) questions about computers (including smartphones with nearly all the capabilities of a PC), computer accessories (such as charging bricks), computer interface things (such as checkboxes), etc. There's also [programming](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) which should be used for (English) questions about programming (and the computer tag is optional I think on these questions).

The tag should not be used for questions where the computer (or programming) aspect of things can be removed, which is what happened in the linked question. Also note that "[n]aming, including naming programming variables/classes" is [off topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (I would not consider the linked question off topic because it has an example sentence.)

Comment: I hope someone update the guidelines for computer tag. I have suggested OP to use `time` tag as suggested by ColleenV.